# How to remind a colleague about myself? Business phrases

Tags: prepositions, word-request, grammaticality

I will delete my question later. How to remind a colleague about myself? Which option is correct?

> 1. I just want to make sure you don't forget **about (or on?)** my request to send a photo.
> 2. I would like to reconfirm that you still remember **about (or on?)** my request to sent the photo.

This is my personal request for work.

Could you please tell me: 'about' or 'on'?

'...a gentle reminder about (or on?) my request to send...'

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Questions and answers are meant to be written in a way that they can help more than just one person, so it would not be a good idea to delete your question once you get an answer. Asking for help phrasing general requests and responses can be on-topic here if you explain which part of what you've written you feel might not be correct.

Comment: As a side note, deleting an answered question once you get what you seek is really discourteous to people who take the time to answer your question.

Comment: You have posted this question on ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477111/how-to-remind-a-colleague-about-myself-business-phrases

Comment: The fact that you say you will (try to) delete this later means that nobody has any incentive to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

How you phrase your reminder may depend on whether the colleague is humoring you by sending a picture, or is fulfilling some company requirement.  This advice is for the latter scenario:

> Just a reminder to please send the photo I mentioned in my email of such and such date.  The company requires blah blah blah ...

If it's a requirement, don't call it a **request**.

Comment: Of course Nick should not actually retain the "blah blah" part.